# Efficient way to execute an insert or update 2 tables SQLITE

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, database, sqlite

I'll walk your through my process step by step so bear with me. So first I attach a sync SQLITE database to my main SQLITE database. Once that attach is complete, I then select all the columns I have available in my main database **(This step here is to avoid any additional columns the sync SQLITE database might have that the main SQLITE database does not have.)**

```
PRAGMA table_info('%@')
```

I then loop through all the columns and format that them into a string.

```
  NSString * pragmaInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PRAGMA table_info('%@')",currentTable];

                        const char *tableInfo = [pragmaInfo UTF8String];
                        NSString * columns;
                        [columnString setString:@""];
                        NSString * lastColumn;
                        sqlite3_stmt * colStatement;
                        if (sqlite3_prepare(threadedMAINDB, tableInfo, -1, &colStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK) {
                            while (sqlite3_step(colStatement)== SQLITE_ROW) {
                                    if (sqlite3_column_text(colStatement, 1)) {
                                      columns = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(colStatement, 1)];
                                    [columnString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",columns]];
                                    lastColumn = columns;
                                }
                            }
                            sqlite3_finalize(colStatement);
```

Here's my current insert or update query. Mind you that it works.

```
//Where columnString is a prepared mutable string of all the columns available in the main SQLITE database
     NSString *tblUpdate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT or REPLACE INTO main.%@ (%@) SELECT %@ FROM sync_db.%@",currentTable, columnString,columnString,currentTable];
```

Now here's my question. Is there a way to grab all the available column names in a table without having to execute AND loop AND prepare a string to eventually plug into INSERT or REPLACE query? I was thinking something along the lines of this query:

```
select column_name
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    where table_name = 'table';
```

I have tried this in my SELECT statement but SQLITE complains about my "." periods.

```
INSERT or REPLACE INTO main.table_name SELECT column_name FROM main.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where sync.table_name = '%@'
```

Hopefully I am clear on this.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has no information schema.

If you don't already know the column names, executing `PRAGMA table_info` is the only way to get them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to retrieve a *statement* of my tables in my SQLite database I have for my app with the following query:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master 
WHERE type IN ('table','view') AND name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_%'
UNION ALL 
SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master 
WHERE type IN ('table','view') 
ORDER BY 1
```

With the statement made by this query, I would loop through each row and I did a string comparison to see if a table has already been created. If the string wasn't found, I would execute the `CREATE TABLE ...` query for the missing table(s)